# Error in Anomaly Detection codes in R Studio

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
**Original Code:**

require("rgdal") 
require("maptools")
require("ggplot2")
require("plyr")
library(devtools)
library(AnomalyDetection)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
Year<-NULL
Year$year<-as.data.frame(as.POSIXlt(data$Year,format = '%Y'))
quakes<-as.data.frame(cbind("Year$year,data$Earthquakes" = FALSE))
quakes<-c('Year','NumberOfQuakes')
ggplot2::fortify(quakes, aes(Year, NumberOfQuakes)) + geom_line() + scale_x_datetime() + 
xlab("") + ylab("Number of Earthquakes")


Output Below

Error in `ggplot2::fortify()`:
! `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a character 
vector.
Backtrace:
1. ggplot2::fortify(quakes, aes(Year, NumberOfQuakes))
2. ggplot2:::fortify.default(quakes, aes(Year, NumberOfQuakes))
```

I'm working on an Anomaly Detection Project - I encounter an Error output
from one of my codes. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: `quakes<-c('Year','NumberOfQuakes')` You turn that object to a vector with those 2 elements.  Did you mean `names(quakes)<-c('Year','NumberOfQuakes')` ?

Comment: That's correct, sir!!